# Disabling "Just -In-Time Debugger" error messages

Tags: visual-studio

Since installing Visual Studio, I often get this kind of error messages when apps crash instead of the regular ones:

[Just-In-Time Debugger http://img20.imageshack.us/img20/8729/errormg.png](http://img20.imageshack.us/img20/8729/errormg.png)
How can I disable this? I've already uninstalled Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to [disable the JIT Debugger in the registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hs4b7a6%28VS.80%29.aspx).